# Cross-platform mobile app with local database, notifications and alarms –– possible in PhoneGap?

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, symbian, phonegap-plugins

I've got a project to port a mobile application I've done for Android phones to iPhone (and Symbian / WP7). I was just wondering if it all could be done in PhoneGap. My personal experience with it is zero, as is with Symbian development too. What I've read, I think the learning curve for PhoneGap is steepish compared to Symbian. I have a pretty solid HTML + CSS background.

The app I need to port has...

- **repeating Notifications – most important feature (one day
  interval after one month has passed since last db record)**
- a small local database (SQlite)
- parse remote xml file (child browser could be considered here as this is
  also presented in flash format).
- list of addresses and google maps integration

Is this all doable in PhoneGap with minimum native code needed? If I understood the docs correctly, PhoneGap does not support native alarm manager API, anyway around this? I saw notification plugins for both iPhone and Android so I think that could be handled.

Any thoughts are all well appriciated, thank you!

**EDIT:** 
Especially that repeating background service/notification thing seems to be hard/impossible with PhoneGap itself, am I correct? 
Any good book recommendations are also welcome. 
Any good PhoneGap plugins site are also welcome. (In addition to the PhoneGap's official plugin page) 
Any good resources for developing / learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all that with PhoneGap. Yes.
If you don't find a PhoneGap plugin that suits your needs 100%, it's easy to extend PGPlugin and implement it's functions. Go for it!!!

Comment: hi, thanks for your input. I've edited the question. I tried to look for plugings but all I ended up was PhoneGap's official plugin page. PhoneGap Beginner's Guide and Beginning PhoneGap are also bought, any other good books / resources?